# Bundle error in asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I got an error (js doesnt work correct) after disabled debuging in web.config.

Error message

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function
>       at main?v=VPdue59YcM75gM2GvOg7lYl5EGJt6x7uXBepa5eFSTk1:3

BundleConfig.cs

bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/js/jquery.min.js"));

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
             "~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"));

    bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/index").Include(
                "~/Scripts/js/isotope.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/js/flexslider.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/js/waypoints.min.js"
               ));   

    bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
       "~/Scripts/js/nicescroll.min.js",
       "~/Scripts/js/pace.min.js"
       ));

    bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
           "~/Scripts/js/custom.js"
          ));
```

The order of connection scripts

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/index")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")
```